# Spring MVC Routing: Trying to pull an element out of URI and into Bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have a url like http://localhost:8080/forum/view/1/ (the last integer being an ID)

I want to then have on this page a "Reply" button, and have it be taken to

http://localhost:8080/forum/view/1/Reply

I want to then pull out the ID (in this case '1'), and pass it into the Controller (as variable postID) for the Reply. What I have so far that I've been toying with is this:

```
<bean name="/view/*/Reply" class="forum.web.NewPostController">
   <property name="postId" value="{1}" />
   <property name="successView" value="../hello.htm" />     
   <property name="formView" value="addReply" />
   <property name="postType" value="R" />
</bean>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `@RequestMapping` annotation. Here is the example from Spring docs:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {

    private final AppointmentBook appointmentBook;

    @Autowired
    public AppointmentsController(AppointmentBook appointmentBook) {
        this.appointmentBook = appointmentBook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> get() {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForToday();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day, Model model) {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForDay(day);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm appointment, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "appointments/new";
        }
        appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
        return "redirect:/appointments";
    }
}
```

More info can be found at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html